# Laravel Livewire hiding bootstrap modal with click event

Tags: bootstrap-modal, laravel-livewire

I am building a livewire-based application which I came to a point where I need `wire:click` event to fire a function in the livewire component class as well as open a Bootstrap Modal.

Without the `wire:click` event, the Bootstrap Modal opens.

Without the Bootstrap Modal `id`, the `wire:click` event works just fine.

With both the two, the Modal opens but hides (not dismissed) forever, until I reload the page before I could do anything.

By default when you create livewire using `php artisan make:livewire --name`, the view part comes with `<div> //comment </div>` tag. So, whenever the place the Modal inside the `div` tag the above problem occurs.

However, if the place the Modal in outside the `div` tag it works fine **BUT NOT RECOGNIZING THE LIVEWIRE VARIABLES**

**I want to know;**

If the livewire doesn't support Bootstrap Modal or having conflicts with the Modal scripts.

If one event can not be fired twice at the same time (`wire:click` and default `click` event).

Why except tags are enclosed inside the `<div> </div>` before livewire recognizes it.

```
<a href="#" wire:click="edit({{ $file->id }})" class="mr-1 edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editFileModal">
    <i class="align-middle fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 16):

By adding `wire:ignore.self` to the root element of my modal fixed it for me.

Modal trigger button.

```
<button wire:click="updateModal({{ $item->id }})" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-label-brand btn-bold" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateModal"> Update</button>
```

Example modal dialog.

```
<div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade" id="kt_modal_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient" class="form-control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient" wire:model="recipient">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="form-control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" wire:model="message"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Alpine.js (that comes with Livewire) to fire both the `wire:click` and the toggle of the modal. By doing this you could even listen for the `wire:click` call to complete before you open the modal, if that suits you better.

```html
<a href="#" x-on:click="$wire.edit({{ $file->id }}); $('#editFileModal').modal('show');" class="mr-1 edit">
    <i class="align-middle fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: I am confused with this alpineJs of a thing. I tried to use it as suggested but not a single event sound to be working. I have added the AlpineJS library as per the Livewire documentation stated, and the above code doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, here is my solution:

Instead of using the attribute data-target="#myModal" to show myModal when the button is clicked, I just use wire:click function to do that. ie:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" wire:click.prevent="myFunction({{$some_id}})">...</button>
```

In myFunction, do whatever you want, after that, add:

```
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('openModal', ['someParameter' => 'some value']);
```

In the view file, add:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('openModal', event => {
$('#myModl').modal('show');
//alert('parameter: ' + event.detail.someParameter);
})
</script>
```

See https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#browser for more info